# ajax - jquery - xml - webservice

Tags: web-services, jquery

I am trying to access the method GetWeatherByPlaceName from the service http://www.webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx. In my "data" attribute included city name as "newyork" but it is not showing any result. Please let me know if it is correct way of representing method name in the url.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"www.webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx/GetWeatherByPlaceName",
        data:"newyork",
        contentType:"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(msg){
          $('span').html(msg);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This isnt working because your breaking the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you either need to use JSONP (if the webservice offers it) or use a server side language to get the result

Comment: thanks for your reply. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Seems that webservice is not working. I am sorry for that. 

I solved this using otherwebservice like this. 

       $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
       dataType: "jsonp",   url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/api-key/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Sweden/Stockholm.json",
        success:function(msg){
      $('span').html(msg['current_observation']['temp_f']);
    }
      });
    });

Comment: Yes - thats using JSONP ... perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, but the service should either receive an url encoded parameters string or a soap formated message.

So, i think you should replace your call by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"www.webservicex.net/weatherforecast.asmx/GetWeatherByPlaceName",
    data:"PlaceName=newyork",
    dataType:"xml",
    success:function(msg){
      $('span').html(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems that webservice is not working. I am sorry for that. 

I solved this using otherwebservice like this. 

       $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
       dataType: "jsonp",   url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/api-key/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Sweden/Stockholm.json",
        success:function(msg){
      $('span').html(msg['current_observation']['temp_f']);
    }
      });
    });